# CellTree node selection reponding only the first time

Tags: gwt, tree, selection

I have a cell tree with a SingleSelectionModel. When I click on a node, it fires an certain action. My problem is that the action is fired only on the first click.

```
public class TreeModel implements TreeViewModel {

private SingleSelectionModel<Entity> selectionModel;


public TreeModel(){
    initialize();
}


private void initialize(){
    selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Entity>();
    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {     
            //fire an action                    
        }
    });
}
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
     ...
     }
```

The CellTree is called normaly

```
CellTree.Resources resource = GWT.create(TreeResources.class);
cellTree = new CellTree(new TreeModel(), null,resource);
panel.add(cellTree);
```

Any clue why it does that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean clicking on the already-selected node? Well, in this case, you're not changing the selection, so there's no `SelectionChangeEvent`.

Maybe you're looking for the `NoSelectionModel`, or for something else than a `SelectionModel` (e.g. a `Cell` that responds to click events, or a `CellPreviewHandler`)